# Scheduling Repeating, Flexible Intervals with Restrictions on Overlap

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, scheduling, process-scheduling

I work in 52:17 work:break intervals, as there's some evidence showing it's an effective way to structure the day. However, meetings or planned breaks often require shifting that schedule, moving, shrinking, or expanding certain parts.

I'm trying to write a program which will do this for me, given a start time, an end time, and a list of calendar events which should either be treated as breaks or sprints. It should return a schedule consisting of as close an approximation to the 52:17 schedule that it reasonably can.

Problem statement:

Input:

- Start of day time
- End of day time
- List of calendar events. User may classify events as "break" (e.g. lunch) or "sprint" (e.g. meetings). These are fixed/immovable.

Output:

- A schedule that approximates the 52:17 intervals, accommodating the aforementioned events.

For example, say I want to work from 8-12 (duration = 240 minutes) uninterrupted. I want to start and end with "sprint". I can find the ideal breakdown as follows:

```
# Every span starts and ends with a sprint right now, 
# though this can be modified later to handle other circumstances
function n_cycles(duration=240, break_time=17, sprint_time=52):
    cycle_time = break_time + sprint_time
    # If we're looking at an interval of less than the break time
    if duration <= break_time:
        # just call it a break
        return -1
    else if duration <= 52 minutes
        # just call it a sprint
        return 0
    else:
        cycles = 1
        accounted_time = sprint_time
        # If adding another cycle would exceed the duration by more than half
        while accounted_time < duration + cycle_time * 1.5:
            accounted_time = accounted_time + cycle_time
            cycles = cycles + 1
        return cycles

function span_interval(start_time, end_time, break_time=17, sprint_time=52):
    cycles = n_cycles(end_time - start_time, break_time, sprint_time)
    if cycles == -1:
        create_event(start_time, end_time, type=break)
    else if cycles == 0:
        create_event(start_time, end_time, type=sprint)
    else:
        duration = end_time - start_time
        ideal_cycle_time = sprint_time + break_time
        proportion = duration / (ideal_cycle_time + ideal_cycle_time * cycles)
        adjusted_sprint_time = sprint_time * proportion
        adjusted_break_time = break_time * proportion
        create_event(start_time, start_time + adjusted_sprint_time, type=sprint)
        start_time = start_time + adjusted_sprint_time
        for i in 0 to cycles:
            create_event(start_time, start_time + adjusted_break_time, type=break)
            start_time = start_time + adjusted_break_time
            create_event(start_time, start_time + adjusted_sprint_time, type=sprint)
            start_time = start_time + adjusted_sprint_time
```

So if we do this, we get:

- 8:00-8:48   Sprint #1
- 8:48-9:03   Break
- 9:03-9:52   Sprint #2
- 9:52-10:07  Break
- 10:07-10:56 Sprint #3
- 10:56-11:11 Break
- 11:11-11:59 Sprint #4

Easy! Optimal!

But say I want to add a work event from 10:00-10:15. Currently, I have a "naive" solution where any sprint event is treated as a whole sprint. Then, recursively, the part of the day *before* and the part of the day *after* are scheduled. Aside from the fact that the above pseudocode must be modified to end the first half with a break and start the second half with a break (easy), this is also obviously not optimal, since we now have a 15 minute sprint with breaks on either side. I could shift sprint #2 back 7 minutes and compensate on either side, but if I have an event that's 3 hours long, I'm going to need to *delete* events, not just shift them.

Any ideas about how I can better approach this problem? I'm interested in search algorithms like GAs, but I can't figure out how to structure the problem such that it can be modular and solutions can be heritable.

EDIT: rephrased and formatted in response to comments from D.W.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, D.W.! Updated. 


Do you have any recommendations for forums where the question would be more appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for the improvements!  I suspect you'll still need to identify an objective function to measure how close a proposed schedule is to satisfactory, before you can find an optimization algorithm to solve this task.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry I forgot to respond sooner. I decided to represent a day as a boolean array, and the objective function as the SSE of each sprint/break from the ideal length.

Comment: I still don't understand what an "event" is.  Is it a desired start time and a desired length?  So "matching" means that you have scheduled it at a time that is close to its desired times?  Is it a desired length, and you are free to schedule it at any time?  It would help to formalize what the inputs are and what the objective function is more clearly.  Rather than clarifying in the comments, we'd prefer that you edit the question.  No need to leave an "EDIT"; we have revision history, so we'd prefer you make it read well for someone who encounters the question for the first time.

Comment: Also I don't understand what a "schedule" is.  If the start time of the day is fixed, end time of the day is fixed, and all events are fixed, then what degree of freedom is left?  It seems like everything is determined and there is nothing left to adjust.